# Azure Cloud service returns error 500 after 30 hours

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, web, cloud

I have a strange problem. I have an MVC 4 application (cloud service) on MS Azure. Application after deployment works fine but after 24-30 hours is returning an error 500. Then I have to reboot the instance. Currently it is running on the machine size S, I have 900 megabytes of free memory and the CPU is at about 3%. I have 1 instance. OS family = 3 (because of .NET framework 4.5)... Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Have you tried to capture any exceptions with diagnostics? Look to see if the app pool is recycling and having a problem doing so since it is a consistent 24-30 hours. Also, if you are getting a 500 from the app try requesting a simple image from the site so you can see if IIS is serving up even static content. Doing any caching which has a floating window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found it. Thanks for idea about app pool. Application pool is automatically recycling after 29 hours (default settings). So I recycled it manually and get error:

Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Data.Entity.dll'

From log I found that the reason is Entity Framework Profiler. I forgot remove it before deploying the app.

Comment: We once had a really weird bug similar to this. To ensure it doesn't happen we had to restart the pool several times during `OnStart()` just to ensure that these restarts work all the times.